# How do I trigger an AJAX request when props is changed?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a this `App` component

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Component1 @addItem="addItem" />
        <Component2 :items="items" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Component1 from './components/Component1'
import Component2 from './components/Component2'

export default {
    name: 'app',

    components: { Component1, Component2 },

    data: function () {
        return {
            items: [],
        }
    },

    methods: function () {
        addItem(item) {
            items.push(item)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

This is my `Component2` component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ ajax_data }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'Component2',

    props: ['items'],

    data: function () {
        return {
            ajax_data: null
        }
    },

    mounted () {
        this.callAJAX()
    },

    methods: {
        callAJAX() {
            axios
                .get('/api/get-some-data', {
                    params: {
                        items: items
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.ajax_data = response.data
                })
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I want to trigger the AJAX everytime I add an item. The problem with my code is since `Component2` is already mounted and when an item is added the AJAX is not running. So then I added this hook:

```
updated () {
    this.callAJAX()
},
```

The problem with this is its running an infinite loop.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply detect if value change with a `watcher`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

in your case, you may set the `deep` property to true...